# Filter and Sort the data from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

I have a stock xls with two sheets:

**TRN HISTORY sheet**

with DATE, SYMBOL, UNITS, PRICE, TYPE, OWNED columns
[image]

| DATE | SYMBOL | UNITS | PRICE | TYPE | OWNED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.2022 | O | 10 | 49.6 | Dividend | Yes |
| 2.2.2022 | IRM | 20 | 31.9 | Dividend | No |
| 3.3.2022 | AAL | 50 | 14.0 | Growth | Yes |

**STOCKS sheet**

with SYMBOL, NAME, STOCK TYPE, UNITS, PRICE columns
[image]

| SYMBOL | NAME | STOCK TYPE | UNITS | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O | Realty Income Corp | Dividend | 10 | 49.6 |

I want to filter out only stocks that are marked as **Yes** in the column **OWNED** (TRN HISTORY sheet) and show them on the main **STOCK** sheet with the corresponding **price**, **number of units**, and **stock type**.

I was able to do that via

```
={"SYMBOL";SORT(FILTER('TRN HISTORY'!B:B;'TRN HISTORY'!F:F="Yes"))}
```

But I do not know how to get the corresponding values from other columns like the **number of units** purchased and the **price once it's sorted alphabetically**.

**Here is the demo xls sheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NpP9IXtQ-Da8t_5G0vfnMXb1o_62tQbR_GuWZTB2GWc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: in your TRN HISTORY whats the NAME ?

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 
 FILTER('TRN HISTORY'!B:F, 'TRN HISTORY'!F:F<>"no"), {4, 2, 3}, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({'TRN HISTORY'!B:E, {"NAME"; 
 BYROW('TRN HISTORY'!B2:B, LAMBDA(x, GOOGLEFINANCE(x, "name")))}}, 
 REGEXMATCH('TRN HISTORY'!F:F, "(?i)yes|owned")), 
 "select Col1,Col5,Col4,Col2,Col3 order by Col1", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer! NAME column is in the STOCKS sheet and there is a function ```={"NAME";BYROW(A2:A; LAMBDA(r; IF(r="";;GOOGLEFINANCE(r; "name"))))}``` which is getting the name of the company based on the Symbol so desired column order is

**SYMBOL, NAME, STOCK TYPE, UNITS, PRICE**

I tried to execute your code and it works, but it also shows one empty row (for IRM which is filtered out by the OWNED="No" value and it's missing the Name column, do you have any idea how to fix those two issues, please? :-)

Comment: It's currently visible in the google drive link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NpP9IXtQ-Da8t_5G0vfnMXb1o_62tQbR_GuWZTB2GWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @vohratom try:  `=FILTER('TRN HISTORY'!B:F, REGEXMATCH('TRN HISTORY'!F:F, "(?i)yes|owned"))`

Comment: well, it shows only two rows now, which is correct but I want it to be **sorted alphabetically** and ideally with another column **NAME** between **SYMBOL** and **UNITS**. Tried to create the ideal look of the table in the columns **H:L** on **STOCKS** xls, do you know how to do that, please? :-)

Comment: @vohratom answer updated

Comment: love you player0! ❤️ Thank you once again, you really helped me to save a ton of time! :-)